# Equivalent of using (s) to indicate possible plural for words using "ies" for plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, suffixes, parentheses, parenthetical-plural

If I want to write how many of something I have that uses "s" to indicate plural, I can use (s), as in "Joe had X apple(s)". But say I want to write something like "The report contains 2 entries" or "The report contains 1 entry". Since the plural of entry isn't "entrys", it seems incorrect to write entry(s). What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: @Josh61 If I want to use something after the word in parentheses to indicate it may or may not be plural, like like how apple(s) could represent apple or apples, would I use entry(s) or something else?

Comment: @WS2 Superb spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always understood that if the word ends in a "y" the plural is written "ies" as; berry(ies) ferry(ies) controversy(ies) belly"ies" as y is that sometimes vowel pronounced ee.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was leaning toward but I wasn't sure if there was a more accepted way

Comment: @thnkwthprtls - be careful..if the y is preceded by a vowel, the s rule applies: donkey, donkeys.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks for the tip, I actually happen to have one of each in what I'm working on so that's definitely good to know

Comment: Also don't make a mistake with proper nouns: `Tommy` -> `Tommy's`, not `Tommie's`.